# Retrieve group value outside the table in report viewer

Tags: crystal-reports, header, reportviewer, paging

I'm writing a report of material grouped by store, and page breaks at the end of each group (store). Therefore each page only displays materials of one store.
[image]

Now I want to display the group name at the top of each page, like we can drag the group name into the header in crystal report.

[image: This is what I want]

I have searched and tried a lot of methods but still cannot get what I want.

Comment: What exactly is it that you want? Can you draw it up in Excel and add a screenshot of the goal?

Comment: What I want is shown in the second page, get the Store number (group name) outside the main table

Comment: It seems like all you need to do is drag your store number column into your group header. Suppress the group footer. Maybe a text element "Store:" and then next to it the column with the store ID so it reads nicely. Then drag your material ID column into the Details section and change the assosiated page header to read "Material". If you can upload some screenshots of your Design tab, including section labels, and then your Preview, it should be easy enough to debug any mistakes.